# printf with newline character causing strange seg. fault

Tags: c, linux

I observed a strange behaviour while executing this code snippet

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char *a[10] = {"hi", "hello", "how"};
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i = 0;i < 10; i++)
            printf("%s\n", a[i]);
}
```

OutPut:

```
hi
hello
how
Segmentation fault
```

But if I replace the '\n' character with a space character in printf statement then no seg. fault is coming

```
hi hello how (null) (null) (null) (null) (null) (null) (null)
```

I am using gcc v4.4.3 on Ubuntu.
How can a newline character cause a seg. fault in printf ?

Comment: I don't understand how that can be described as "strange"...

Comment: How about `for (i = 0;i < 3; i++)` since you have a pointer to **3** arrays?

Answer (score 6):

What you have is [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You have an array of ten pointers to `char`, but only the three first actually points to something valid while the rest of the pointers are `NULL` pointers. Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer leads to undefined behavior, which can *sometime* work, and other time it will crash your program.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't the C standard require %s with NULL to still be defined behavior?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Just checked to be sure, the C11 specification doesn't say anything about it.

Answer (score 5):

The difference in behavior is due to the fact that gcc optimizes `printf("%s\n", ...)` to `puts(...)`, which is functionally the same, except when the string is`NULL`.

In the second case, gcc can't optimize the call, thus the different output.

Answer (score 1):

You are having Undefined Behavior. You are initialized only 3 pointer, the rest of them are pointing to `NULL`. when you are trying to print the `NULL` pointer Leads to undefined Behavior.

Try the following way it will work for you.

```
void main()
{
char a[10][10] = {"hi", "hello", "how"}; // here statically i am allocating array. 
// First three elements are initialized and the remaining elements contains null.
int i = 0, j = 0;
for (i = 0;i < 10; i++)
        printf("%s\n", a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the first three items in the array are initialised (by the three strings).  You need to initialise the other seven char * pointers before trying to access them.

Answer (score -1):

You initialized only 3 out of 10 array members. The behaviour of accessing uninitialized pointers is undefined. Sometimes it crashes, sometimes not.

Comment: When an array or struct is initialized from a brace-enclosed initializer, any members that don't have initializers get initialized as if `0` was given.  So the other pointers are initialized to being null pointers.

Comment: @kristianp uninitialized is *not* equivalent to NULL. In fact, MSVC in debug often "initializes" uninitialized values to 0xCCCCCCCC.